# changing images along the home screen transition

Tags: android, live-wallpaper

I'm trying to create a simple livewallpaper which slides images with the home screen slides.
so I wrote this code. It worked in some devices, but I got Out Of Memory error in several devices.
I know it takes a lot of memory to hold several large images.

Does someone has any idea to solve this Out Of Memory problem?

```
void drawFrame() {
    SurfaceHolder holder = getSurfaceHolder();
    Canvas c;
    if(mScreenNo < 1 || isPreview() || offsetOK == false){
        Log.d("drawFrame","mScreenNo < 1 || isPreview()");
        c = holder.lockCanvas();
        c.drawBitmap(bg_I, 0, bgY, p);
    }else{
    float bg_w = bg_I.getWidth();
    Float[] bg_x = new Float[mScreenNo +1];

    for(int i=0; i < bg_x.length; i++){
        bg_x[i] = bgX + bg_w * i;
    }

        c = holder.lockCanvas();

    Log.d("draw"," bgX="+bgX);

    for(int i=0; i < bg_x.length; i++){
        switch(i%3){
        case 0:
        c.drawBitmap(bg_I, bg_x[i], bgY, p);
        break;
        case 1:
        c.drawBitmap(bg_II, bg_x[i], bgY, p);
        break;
            case 2:
        c.drawBitmap(bg_III, bg_x[i], bgY, p);
        break;
            }
    }
    }

    holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
    handler.removeCallbacks(drawThread);
    if (visible)
    handler.postDelayed(drawThread, 25);
    }
    }
```

at onOffsetChanged, I do like this.

```
        @Override
        public void onOffsetsChanged(float xOffset, float yOffset, float xStep,
                float yStep, int xPixels, int yPixels) {
            mXoffset = xOffset;
            mXStep = xStep;
            mXPixels = xPixels;
            mScreenNo = (int)(1/mXStep);//Number of screens(-1)
            mPageNo = (int)(mXoffset / mXStep);//current screen page(the first page is 0)
            mWallStep = getWallpaperDesiredMinimumWidth()/2 /mScreenNo;
            float mwall_screen = rescale.getScreenWidth() / mWallStep;
            bgX = mXPixels * mwall_screen;
            offsetOK = true;
}
```

I need your help!
waiting for your great idea. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

i just solved the problem by myself.
maybe it is a silly way to solve, but it works well now.

how i solved the problem was just modifying the for loop as below:

```
    for(int i=0; i < bg_x.length; i++){
    if(-bg_w < bg_x[i]&& bg_x[i] <= bg_w){
        Log.d("drawFrame","draw this time");
        switch(i%3){
        case 0:
            c.drawBitmap(bg_I, bg_x[i], bgY, p);
            break;
        case 1:
            c.drawBitmap(bg_II, bg_x[i], bgY, p);
            break;
        case 2:
            c.drawBitmap(bg_III, bg_x[i], bgY, p);
            break;
        }
    }else{
        Log.d("drawFrame","no draw this time");
    }
}
```

hope this would help someone.